# Как обратиться к определенному объекту класса

Tags: c++, ооп, vector

Заполняется вектор, как можно потом обратиться к определенному объекту класса?

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    srand(time(NULL));

    std::vector<Book>::iterator ITER;
    const int N = 3;
    std::vector<Book> Arr(N);
    for (ITER = Arr.begin(); ITER != Arr.end(); ++ITER)
    {

    std::cout << "Объем книги: "  << ITER->getVolume() << " страниц" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Возрастные ограничения: " << ITER->getAgeRestrictions() << "+" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Оценка книги: " << ITER->getMarks() << "+" << std::endl; //убрать 
    std::cout << "Жанр книги: " << ITER->getGenre() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Название книги: " << ITER->getNameBook() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Автор книги: " << ITER->getAuthorBook() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: К *определенному* — какому именно? Как вы его определяете?

Comment: например, мне нужно получить информацию насчет второй книги,

Comment: Arr[1] - вторая книга

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант как можно реализовать без ITER:

```
class Book
{
    public:
        Book(int i){
            field = i;
        }
        int getField() const
        {
            return field;
        }
        int field;
};

int main ()
{
    const int N = 3;
    std::vector<Book> Arr(N, Book(0));
    Arr[0].field = 1;
    Arr[1].field = 2;
    Arr[2].field = 3;
      
    for(const auto book: Arr)
    {
        cout << "Field: "  << book.field << " " << book.getField() << endl;
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Field: 1 1
Field: 2 2
Field: 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

> например, мне нужно получить информацию насчет второй книги

Если это вектор или дек — словом, с произвольным доступом — можно по индексу

```
Arr[2].getMarks()
```

В общем случае — через итератор:

```
auto it = std::next(Arr.begin(),1);
it->getMarks();
```